# Styling Radio buttons and Checkboxes in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, radio-button

After following various online tutorials on how to style my Radio buttons and Checkboxes. I have managed with the following code:

```
.radio input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.radio input:checked:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  background: #99a1a7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-shadow: 0px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.radio input:checked {
  background-color: #e9ecee;
  color: #99a1a7;
  border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

This works for modern browsers, it gives me the following:

[image: radio buttons]

Unfortunately I must support IE8 too, and the above does not work for IE8. I know that the `:checked` pseudo element does not work for IE8, so I have the [following script](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) that is supposed to provide me with that functionality.

I also have a conditional CSS comment that brings in a stylesheet specifically for IE8.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ie8-styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The first thing I want to know is, does IE8 support something like this (bear in mind the JS script)?

```
.radio input:checked:after {
    content: "boo";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    background: #99a1a7;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    text-shadow: 0;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

I'm curious if it'll read the double pseudo elements of `:checked:after` because right now I don't see the word `boo` before my radio buttons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not opposed to using JS, you might want to checkout http://selectivizr.com/. We have used this in several projects that require older browser support and functional custom style checkboxes/radios.

Comment: Does it support `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors? I can't see any documentation! And on the home page, `:before` and `:after` are not mentioned in the list!

Comment: Yeah it does. obviously this needs to be used in conjunction with one of the other libraries mentioned, JQuery for example. But should help with your requirements. Also to be more performant you can use IE conditionals to load it in for only the older browsers too!

Comment: hmm it isn't working for me. I'm using IE11 but made it emulate IE8. Can that be the cause of why my Radio buttons are not re-drawn from the `:before` and `:after`?

Comment: well compat mode is not actually really very good for testing compatibility and I have had various issues using that method rather than the native browser you are testing itself before. Could be worth chekcing in an actual IE8 browser. Couldn't tell for sure I'm afraid without seeing. But both pseudo elements are covered with selectivizr for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the 'hide the input' and use an image on larger projects, but for simpler projects that run on IE8, I use the following CSS, and it works perfect. This has a negligible effect on newer browsers. The height/width has no effect unless you add the background-color. This would be great for an IE8 specific style-sheet.

```
input[name="bdu"] {height:1em; width:1em; background-color:#000;}
```

And the html..

```
<input name='bdu' type='radio' value='S'/> SET
```

Here are 3 examples, pulled right off a working page.. No CSS, 1em and 2em.

[image: Normal Radio Buttons]

[image: 1em Size]

[image: 2em Size]